# my implementation of viewpager confused me a lot on fragment/activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am running a tab pager adapter but I cannot seem to understand how to implement code not located in the Main Activity. Some codes that I made requires that I extend Activity making it impossible since I have already extended fragment. Can anyone enlighten me on this?

```
public class Home extends Fragment{
    ListView list;
    String url = "http://blog.compassion.com/living-in-the-philippines-rural-life/";
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView titlebutton = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        titlebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new Title().execute();
                }
        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container);
    }


    private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String body;
        String title;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements elements = document.select("p");
                title = document.title();
                for(Element elements123 : elements){
                    body+=elements123.text();
                    System.out.println(elements123.text());

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                TextView txttbody = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                txttbody.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                txttbody.setText(title +"\n"+body);
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
    }
```

Comment: did you ask any problem, you just told us your mood. whats the problem?

Comment: my code isn't working. It has nullpointer on the onCreateView part.

Answer (score 0):

To use this viewPager in your main class you need to extend the class FragmentActivity. The viewPager activity is not a fragment, but the pages inside of each tab of the viewPager are fragments, so you use a FragmentActivity to control them. Also, make sure you use the android.support.v4 versions of imports whenever they are available.

Comment: But how should I be setting the contentView on each fragment? whenever I try to write some functions on these fragments, they doesn't seem to reflect.

Comment: Step 1: Home extends FragmentActivity.Step 2: get the action bar. Step 3: actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS Step 4: set up listener for action bar tabs. In the layout file you need to have android.support.v4.view.ViewPager as the root layout. You need to make separate content views fro each fragment. Look at this page. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: I have a getItem method which returns a fragment type. It has a switch which returns a fragment depending on the index. What should i do about it?

Comment: @LeoComia look at this. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Answer (score 0):

this solves your `NPE` in your `onCreatView`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              view v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView titlebutton = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            titlebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    new Title().execute();
                    }
            });
            return v;
        }
```

Comment: it says the specified child has already a parent? i don't understand

Comment: post line number, but NPE has gone yes?